# SwiftUI localization swizzle on NSBundle

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI when using a view like `Text("some value")`, the SwiftUI framework automatically assumes `"some value"` is a `LocalizedStringKey` and it fetches the stored localized value from `Localizable.strings` (based on the locale).

For example:

```
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("some value")
  }
}
```

```
//Localizable.strings
"some value" = "the translated value";
```

And the result would show `"the translated value"` on the screen.

In order to return custom localized values dynamically (in runtime), instead of the ones in `Localizable.strings`, I tried to swizzle the `Bundle.main` method which handles localization by the UIKit framework:

`Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: "some value", value: "default-value", table: nil)`

This is how the swizzle performed in my case:

```
func swizzleLocalizationMethods() {
  let originalSelector = #selector(localizedString(forKey:value:table:))

  guard let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector) else { return }

  let customSelector = #selector(customLocalizedString(forKey:value:table:))

  guard let customMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, mySelector) else { return }

  method_exchangeImplementations(orginalMethod, customMethod)
}
```

Then in `customLocalizedString`, I could return a desired value based on the key in runtime.

The above works perfectly in a UIKit project, since in my project have always use directly `NSLocalizedString("some value", "")`

For example:

```
myLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("some value", "")
```

But seems in SwiftUI localization works differently internally, when trying to use `Text("some value")`, because the swizzled method, `customLocalizedString` is not being called unless I explicitly use it like this:

```
Text(NSLocalizedString("some value", ""))
```

Something which I want to avoid, and keep using it more cleanly like this `Text("some value")`

**My question:**
Does it mean SwiftUI has some other internal way when it loads the `Localizable.strings` keys I set when using `Text("key")`, instead of going through the method `Bundle.main.localizedString(...)`?

Does anyone know more about it?

Thanks